# click event Jquery

Tags: jquery, events, click

guys tried everything, it doesn't see the event happening when clicking on the button, when I put the same code into console works perfectly but from editor doesn't...

```
$(function(){

//neither this or
    //$("#backbtn").click(function(){console.log($(this))});

//this works...
    $('#backbtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this));
    });

//this works perfectly
    $(".singlebutton").click(function() {

        $(".singlebutton").toggle();
        $("#addition").slideToggle();

    });


    console.log("yeap works till here");
});
```

here is the button that I try to click

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="backbtn">
        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" style="font-size: 1.5em;"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain exactly what will happen when you click on the button with id "backbtn". Also there is no html for .singlebutton and #addition. I can get the console content as [object Object],while clicking button "#backbtn".